# What is the gödel number of 'SSS(0)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic, prime-numbers

I am only familiar with getting Godel numbers with having a sequence of positive numbers with length k + 1, and then multiplying sequence of prime numbers raised to the power of that given sequence of positive numbers.

But what happens in this case when I have a primitive recursive function 'SSS(0)'? Do I have to replace each symbol with it's symbol number, so it becomes <4 3 2> ? Or is it just a single number 4, since 0 represents 1? If it is a single number then would my Godel number be 2^4 and that's it? Or should I just use prime factorization and have SSS(0) = 2^2 ?

I am really confused, I guess I am lacking something fundamental in here, I spent hours on internet and reading book but I cant find a similar example.

Comment: SSS(0) isn't a primitive recursive function, it's a number.

Comment: Yeah, I asked if it is just a single number 4, since 0 represents 1. If it is then how do I get a Godel number out of a single number?

Comment: You should think of assigning Godel numbers to *strings of symbols*, not to numbers, or functions, or . . . Also, keep in mind that there are many systems of Godel numbering. For instance, maybe I assign "S" to 1, "(" to 2, ")" to 3, and "0" to 4 - then I might code the string "SSS(0)" as  the number $2^13^15^17^211^413^3$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber and also if its a single number, then what does it refer to? 4 or 3? Should I count 0 as 0 or as 1 since that is what a godel number for 0 is?

Comment: So if anything can be assigned to symbols, then does it mean that there is no single fundamental way of finding Godel Number of a given expression?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "no single fundamental way" - there are many different ways to code strings of symbols as natural numbers, which are "effective" enough for Godel's lemmas to hold of them. So in that sense, no, I would argue that there's not a unique "best" one. But at the same time, in a precise sense they're all "equivalent," so in that sense there *is* a unique one (up to a certain notion of equivalence). What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I guess if I am not given any preassigned codes between symbols and integers, like I cannot say that "S" is 1 or whatsoever, what would be the right approach for this problem? Is there a fundamental mapping between "S" and a number maybe?

Comment: I don't understand your question - what do you mean by "a fundamental mapping?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf{0}$ represents... $0$, not too surprisingly. $\mathbf{SSS0}$ is a constant term, not a primitive recursion function or even an expression denoting one.

Just what the Gödel number of the term is depends on the particular scheme of Gödel numbering you're using. In [Gödel's original paper](http://mrob.com/pub/math/goedel.html), $\mathbf{0}$ is assigned to $1$, $\mathbf{S}$ is assigned to $3$. In that system, the expression would be $\mathbf{SSS0}$ with no parentheses. Its Gödel number is:
$$
\#\mathbf{SSS0} = 2^3 3^3 5^3 7^1 = 8\cdot 27\cdot 125\cdot 7 = 189,000.
$$

Comment: So does it mean that SSS(0) refer to a constant term 3?

Comment: Yes, it denotes $3$: the successor of the successor of the successor of $0$.

Comment: I think I'm starting to see the confusion - the *meaning* of a term (e.g., SSS0 means 3) is a different thing than the *Godel number* of the term, which is a *name* for the term. (Note that this name will be a number, which can be represented as a numeral, which will have its own Godel code - so we can have names for names, and names for names for names, and . . .https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haddocks%27_Eyes, but that's maybe a bit silly. :P)

Comment: @NoahSchweber (I didn't notice at first that *you* had written the previous post, I thought OP had come quite a ways :D ) Right, +1, they are quite different things. As we've just seen, ... $3 \ne 189000$ ;) Furthermore, $189000$ is an integer, but $\mathbf{S\cdots S0}$ with $189000$ $\mathbf{S}$s is a term, which has a (huge) Godel number. It's seldom necessary to go beyond that, two levels indirection. But the proof of incompleteness (&, I suppose, if you squint, the recursion theorem) does go that far.